# Cross compile SDL2 in C for Windows on Linux

Tags: c, cross-compiling, sdl-2

I have an SDL2 program that I've been developing on Ubuntu that I'd like to compile for windows. Right now I compile and run it with a makefile like this:

```
OBJECTS = main.o text.o object.o vector.o physics.o shapes.o target.o
run: all
    ./a.out
all: $(OBJECTS)
    gcc $(OBJECTS) `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2_image -lm -ldl

main.o: main.c defs.h
    gcc -c main.c `sdl2-config --cflags --libds` -lSDL2_ttf

text.o: text.c text.h defs.h
    gcc -c text.c

object.o: object.c object.h defs.h
    gcc -c object.c

vector.o: vector.c vector.h defs.h
    gcc -c vector.c

physics.o: physics.c physics.h defs.h
    gcc -c physics.c

shapes.o: shapes.c shapes.h defs.h
    gcc -c shapes.c

target.o: target.c target.h defs.h
    gcc -c target.c

clean:
    rm *.o
```

Comment: `--libds` - a typo?

Comment: Also where is `OBJECTS` defined? You should post your actual makefile, and the sources too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [quasi-msys2](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2) cross-compilation environment (I'm the author).

From the first glance, your makefile should work in it with minimal changes:

- `sdl2-config` doesn't work there (which is a minor defect), but `pkg-config` does.

  Replace `sdl2-config` with `pkg-config sdl2 SDL2_image SDL2_ttf` (followed by `--libs` and/or `--cflags`).

  Then `-lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2_image` should be removed, since pkg-config is going to output those anyway.

  Note that `pkg-config ... --libs` should be used when linking, and `pkg-config --cflags` should be used when compiling (same with `sdl2-config`).
- `-ldl` should be removed. `-lm` is unnecessary, but should be harmless.
- `gcc` should be replaced with `$CC` to pick up the compiler from the environment variable.
- While this doesn't affect correctness, manually specifying `.h` dependencies in makefiles is error-prone and tedious. Instead you should be compiling with `-MMD -MP` flags, to automatically generate the dependencies.

  Since removing the dependencies makes all your `.o` recipes look very similar, you can deduplicate them into a single recipe:

  ```
  %.o : %.c
      $CC -c $< -MMD -MP
  ```

  `-MMD -MP` is going to produce `.d` files (tiny makefile pieces), which need to be included using `-include $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)`.

With those fixes, the makefile should work in quasi-msys2, except that the resulting executable is going to be called `a.exe` and not `a.out`...

```bash
# We're going to cross-compile with Clang. Install Clang, LLD, Wine. Then...

# Clone the repo
https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2
cd quasi-msys2

# Install the necessary packages
make install _gcc _SDL2 _SDL2_image _SDL2_ttf

# Open the cross-compilation shell
# Among other things, this sets `CC` to a wrapper for Clang that invokes it 
# with the right flags, and sets env variables for `pkg-config` to find the
# newly installed libs.
env/shell.sh
```

Then just run `make` as usual.